# Where can the logs of a SP Designer workflow be viewed?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Some SharePoint Designer actions have an option to "log" a message at that point in the workflow. Where are these logs available for viewing after the workflow actually runs? I checked under the Item's "Workflows" button and can see that the workflow ran and what time it ran, but no messages are logged. Is this the correct location and my workflow is failing to log anything, or am I looking in the wrong place? I'm using SP Designer 2010 with SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workflow step `Log SomeText to the workflow history list` will create an item in the Workflow History list. By default, that list is hidden from the browser, but you can manually enter its URL in the address bar:

```
http://yourSitePath/Lists/Workflow%20History/AllItems.aspx
```

Since it's a URL, you need to type the %20 for the space between `Workflow` and `History`.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. Perhaps because I'm using a Form Library?

Comment: Workflow History is the default history list, but other lists can be applied. Try this: In SharePoint Designer, look at the workflow settings. The name of the history list is showing in the Settings panel. You can then change the settings of that list to be visible in the browser.

Comment: Given URL did not worked for me either, but this one works - `http://yourSitePath/Lists/WorkflowHistory/AllItems.aspx`

Answer (score 1):

Open website in SharePoint Designer -> Workflows -> Select your Workflow-> Open History list